# I am using jasmine framework with Phantomjs. getting error while running test case "Expected an identifier but found 'jasmineRequire' instead"

Tags: phantomjs, karma-jasmine, angular14

I am using angular 14 version.
test case framework is jasmine and using Phantomjs broswer on karma file
while running test I am getting these two errors

> Expected an identifier but found 'jasmineRequire' instead "/node_modules/karma-jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:25:0 "in jasmine js

> Can't find variable: jasmineRequire in boot.js file

I need to run test case with Phantomjs